# Symfony2 Form is automatically generated even when form_widget not specified

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I'm using Symfony2 and TWIG to render the form, there is only this code in the TWIG template and the Symfony is rendering all rows:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

In my previous project in Symfony I was able to render each field like this:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form.name) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form_end` outputs `form_rest()` if You do not set it to false (from [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-end-view-variables)):

```
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```